# Pointwise Mutual Information (PMI) and Information Component (IC)

Tags: natural-language, mutual-information, signal-detection

Pointwise Mutual Information (PMI) and the Information Component (IC) formula (https://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00002018-200225060-00002) seem to be the same, PMI is mainly used in natural language processing applications (e.g. https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/li15/lec3.vector.pdf), while IC is mainly used in signal detection and association analysis. Are they the same concepts with different names in different domains?